# How to update an instance without one of the params from the instance_params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crud, parameters

I have a user_controller with an update method. Depending on where the user comes from, I sometimes have to pass the edit form for the user an extra param (:tournament) that actually don't update the user instance but helps me to redirect the user to the right page at the end of the update action.

Here's my update method :

```
  def update
    authorize @user
    if @user.subscriptions.exists? && !@user.judge? && user_params[:birthdate].present?
      flash[:alert] = "Vous ne pouvez plus modifier votre date de naissance après vous etre inscrit à une compétition. Merci de contacter l'administrateur du site"
      redirect_to user_path(current_user)
    elsif @user.update(user_params)
      if @user.judge? && @user.profile_complete? && !@user.accepted
        UserMailer.judge_waiting_for_confirmation(@user).deliver
        redirect_to user_path(current_user)
      else
        redirect_to user_path(current_user)
      end
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

Problem is in the elsif when I try to update my user with user_params, it throws me an error `unknown attribute 'tournament' for User.`

My user params looks like that :

```
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(
      :extradoc,
      :address,
      :birthdate,
      :certifmedpicture,
      :club,
      :email,
      :first_name,
      :genre,
      :judge_number,
      :last_name,
      :licence_number,
      :licencepicture,
      :login_aei,
      :name,
      :password_aei,
      :picture,
      :ranking,
      :telephone,
      :sms_forfait,
      :sms_quantity,
      :tournament
    )
  end
```

How can I update my user without the :tournament param while at the same time permitting it so I can use it to redirect my user to the right place at the end of the action ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create `attr_accessor` for `tournament` attribute to achieve this.

So go into your user model and create `attr_accessor` for `tournament` like below :

```
attr_accessor :tournament
```

Now you can set tournament value in your form. Remove `tournament` from `user_params`.

You can get value in `params[:user][:tournament]` check and redirect. Also your object will update properly.

Comment: when I remove :tournament from user_params I still get found unpermitted parameter: tournament

Comment: @DavidGeismar not removing it from your params is also an option. You can still leave the attr_accessor on you user model, so you're user instance knows about this attribute.